# Add, remove and rename input jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input, addition, rename

i took the code below on the internet, but i have no ideia how when i add or remove a input automatically the input's rename.

html

```
<input type="text" value="" id="qta_alternativas" size="4" /><div id="div_01"><a href="#" id="add">Adicionar</a></div>
        <div id="div_03">
          <div id="p_scents">
            <p>
              <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_1" />
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
    $(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#add').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_' + i +'" /><a href="#" id="remove_opcao">Remover</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            document.getElementById('qta_alternativas').value = i-1;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remove_opcao').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
                    document.getElementById('qta_alternativas').value = i-1;
            }
            return false;
    });

    $("input[name^=opcao_]").each(function(index) {
        this.name = "opcao_" + index;
    });
```

});

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_1" />
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_2" />
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_3" />
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_4" />
```

if i remove the input name="opcao_3", my code will get like:

```
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_1" />
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_2" />
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_4" />
```

but i want when i remove my code get like:

```
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_1" />
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_2" />
<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="50" name="opcao_3" />
```

How can i do that?! Someone can help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Show us the function you have to remove an input.  It just needs modifying slightly to rename the remaining ones.  Also, you shouldn't have elements with the same ID. That should be changed.

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code?

Comment: FYI, `id` should be unique

Comment: why you don't just remove the opcao_4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code to my code.. and it is working!!

```
$(document).delegate('a','click',function()
{
    $( this ).parent('p').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the end of the remove click handler...

```
$("input[name^=opcao_]").each(function(index) {
    this.name = "opcao_" + index;
});
```

It will go through all the inputs with a name attribute that begins with "opcao_" and rename them using an index.

Comment: it doesn't work :(
i tried it before too, but i don't know why it didn't work

Comment: Until you've got rid of all the duplicate IDs (and I suspect there are more than we've seen above) then you're going to have problems.  That code will do exactly what you've asked, so if it's not working then there's a problem somewhere else.  Do you get any errors in the console?